# git push to alternative master rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote

Tags: git

I have two repos. One for production and one for staging. alt (staging) have some files and external contacts working on it. Cannot delete. Want to push codes from local (origin prod), to staging (alt). Added these two remotes and they look like this:

```
$ git remote -v
alt     https://github.com/uname/staging.git (fetch)
alt     https://github.com/uname/staging.git (push)
origin  https://bitbucket.com/uname/prod.git (fetch)
origin  https://bitbucket.com/uname/prod.git (push)
```

Tried to push to staging:

```
$ git push staging master
To https://github.com/uname/staging.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/uname/staging.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Answer (score 2):

Please can you try `git pull origin` so your current branch is updated with the necessary code. Once you have resolved merge conflicts you will be able to continue with your push.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself. Ran:

`git pull origin` got message about pulling not possible because unmerged files. 
 `git add --all` to add untracked files (misc.xml). 
 `git commit -m "adding untracked files"` and 
 
forced push with `git push origin HEAD:master --force`